# Training LDA on Wikipedia corpus to tag arbitary article?

Tags: python, nltk, gensim

I followed the steps in gensim Python https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html to train wikipedia on LDA model, now I want to compare arbitary article from cnn.com for example with the trained data, what do I need to do next? Suppose this article is in txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken [from here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html):

```
# Create a new corpus, made of previously unseen documents.
cnn_article = [
    ['This', 'is', 'my', 'cnn', 'article'],
    ]
other_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in cnn_article]
unseen_doc = other_corpus[0]
vector = lda[unseen_doc] # get topic probability distribution for a document
```

Then get the similarities by using [gensims Similarity class](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/similarities/docsim.html).

**Update:**

To more precisely refer to the tutorial and your text file:

```
# Create a corpus from a list of texts
common_dictionary = Dictionary(common_texts)
common_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in common_texts]

# Train the model on the corpus.
lda = LdaModel(common_corpus, id2word=common_dictionary, num_topics=10)

# optional: print topics of your model
for topic in lda.print_topics(10):
    print(topic)

# load your CNN article from file
with open("cnn.txt", "r") as file:
    cnn = file.read()

# split article into list of words and make this list an element of a list
cnn = [cnn.split(" ")]

cnn_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in cnn]

unseen_doc = cnn_corpus[0]
vector = lda[unseen_doc] # get topic probability distribution for a document

# print out «similarity» of cnn article to each of the topics
# bigger number = more similar to topic 
print(vector)
```

Comment: ok, but am not able to relate this example with the results I have in the LDA trained wikipedia https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html

Comment: How exactly are you unable to relate this? This is more or less exactly the example that is given at the end of the tutorial: «As usual, a trained model can used be to transform new, unseen documents (plain bag-of-words count vectors) into LDA topic distributions: `doc_lda = lda[doc_bow]`»

Comment: sorry, am not a strong programmer, where do I add the trained wikipedia result in the script you mentioned above? also can I make cnn_article=loaded text file? or I should conert it to vecto/matrix?